# BindingProxy does not work within ListView

Tags: wpf

This does work as expected. The Text2 is only required if the Text1 contains a predefined value (comes from myConverter1):

```
        <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter1" />
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy1" Data="{Binding}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBox Width="120">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Text1" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="120">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Text2" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                            <local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule.Params>
                                <local:ValueRequiredValidationParams IsRequired="{Binding Data.Text1, Source={StaticResource proxy1}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter1}, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:ValueRequiredValidationParams>
                            </local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule.Params>
                        </local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

But when I make the same within a ListView, it does not work:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter2" />
            <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy2" Data="{Binding}" />
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Text1" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Width="120">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Text1" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" />
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Text2" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="120">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Text2" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                                                <local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule.Params>
                                                    <local:ValueRequiredValidationParams IsRequired="{Binding Data.Text1, Source={StaticResource proxy2}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter2}, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:ValueRequiredValidationParams>
                                                </local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule.Params>
                                            </local:BindableValueRequiredValidationRule>
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Here the other stuff:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var x = value as string;
        if (x == "aa")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ValueRequiredValidationParams : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "IsRequired", typeof(bool), typeof(ValueRequiredValidationParams), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

    public bool IsRequired
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRequiredProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsRequiredProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public class BindableValueRequiredValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public ValueRequiredValidationParams Params { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (!Params.IsRequired)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, "");
        }
        var x = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, "");
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Items
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text1;

    private string _text2;

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set
        {
            _text1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _text2; }
        set
        {
            _text2 = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Text1 = "aa";
        vm.Text2 = "";

        var list = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
        list.Add(vm);
        var data = new Data
        {
            Items = list
        };

        //DataContext = vm;
        DataContext = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding is just broken, which your output window probably would have told you.

Your proxy exists at the level of the `ListView` and binds to the top level `DataContext` which is an object with an `Items` property, you however try to bind to `Data.Text1`, there is no `Text1` at that level. You would need to create the proxy at the level of the list items. Not sure if that is even possible with resources like that; try putting it into the `TextBox.Resources` (same cell template).